# Find source of javascript modifcation of an element in chrome before page is fully loaded

Tags: javascript, debugging

When my page is fully loaded, the body tag is set to display block, but by default its display none. How does one debug and find where in the javascript files that is making this body display block after the page is fully loaded? And no, the display block is not in the html. It's somehwere in one of the js files. I'm not sure how to look for this.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest the debugger in the Chrome DevTools (or equivalents). You can set breakpoints at the beginning of your javascript, and go step by step until you find the culprit. If this is triggered early, it shouldn't take too long to find.

Comment: i did set a breakpoint. it didnt work.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the first script, assert that the element doesn't yet have the attribute, then install a DOM change breakpoint

Comment: where is this dom change breakpoint